# Is there a way to convert .xlsx and .xls file into tab delimited text files in CODE

Tags: c#, excel, wcf

I'm writing a WCF service which accepts an an Excel file (xls/xlsx) as a byte array, and now I need to convert it into a format I can read. Earlier I had tried this using Interop.Excel, but  this was working only on my local machine, and Not on the server. Apparently I needed MS Excel installed on my server, which is not recommended. I have 2 options-

1. either use a third party library to read the byte excel file
2. convert the byte file to a text format and read it from there(this is already written in my service)

I'm trying to go with #2 for now. Any ideas as to how I can begin with this

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How do you expect to convert it without first reading it? You'll need a 3rd party library either way.

Comment: Agree with Cory Nelson. You will need a 3rd party library atleast to read the file. After reading it you can convert it into any text format that you want.

Comment: Find a library that allows you to read the Excel file (I recommend [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)), get the data, then use a StringBuilder and File.WriteAllText() to generate your text file. Things are much easier when you break them down into their component steps.

Comment: OpenXml SDK can help you with reading .xlsx and it is pure .NET and  supported by M$ guys; as for .xls I have no idea. You can try to handle .xlsx yourself (its essentially zip with bunch of xml files) - but good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give a try to the option of the Interop.Excel referenced on the server, if you know that everyone using the service will be using a Windows OS and they have the same office version.

Good luck!

Comment: Did you read the question? "Earlier I had tried this using Interop.Excel, but this was working only on my local machine, and Not on the server. Apparently I needed MS Excel installed on my server, which is not recommended."

Comment: Yes, I did. And that is the reason why I suggest to give it a try. You will need MS Office installed on the server (and if you want to generate and to work with Office docs through WCF this make sense to me, so I think it worth the time to try it)